# JavaScript returns value from Servlet to one Jsp but not the Second one

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

so I have 2 JSP files and I need one kind of data in both of them. So I figured I'm gonna use one Servlet to get the data from my SQL database. Somehow one JSP gets the JSON Object but the other only receives an empty string. Both JS files have an "Onload" listener:
For visual example see masterpiece down below.

I have the following code in both JavaScript files for log output.

```
console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
console.log("Site succ. loaded")
```

In one jsp I get the output:

```
{"testnum":1,"teststring":"testtest"}
Site succ. loaded
```

In the other I get

```
<empty String>
Site succ. loaded
```

What is the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: So what is different? It is impossible for us to tell

Comment: Thats the problem. There is no difference. The outcome is still different somehow

Comment: Well something is... Your question is impossible to answer.